# Building CPython using clang invokes /usr/bin/ld for final link, and gets "/usr/bin/ld: error: libpython3.2m.a: malformed archive header name at 8"

Tags: python, llvm, llvm-clang

I'm attempting to build CPython 3.2 using llvm's clang.  It builds OK with gcc.  I'm on Linux Mint 12.

The compile seems to go fine until the end, where it attempts to produce the ./python binary.  The error I get is:

```
clang -pthread   -Xlinker -export-dynamic -o python Modules/python.o libpython3.2m.a -lpthread -ldl  -lutil   -lm
/usr/bin/ld: error: libpython3.2m.a: malformed archive header name at 8
./Modules/python.c:25: error: undefined reference to 'PyMem_Malloc'
./Modules/python.c:27: error: undefined reference to 'PyMem_Malloc'
./Modules/python.c:51: error: undefined reference to '_Py_char2wchar'
./Modules/python.c:59: error: undefined reference to 'Py_Main'
./Modules/python.c:61: error: undefined reference to 'PyMem_Free'
./Modules/python.c:63: error: undefined reference to 'PyMem_Free'
./Modules/python.c:64: error: undefined reference to 'PyMem_Free'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've tried with the llvm 2.9 that's in my trusty Linux Mint 12 .deb repo, and with an SVN trunk of llvm from earlier today, but both give the same errors.

It occurs to me that perhaps things would go better if I could persuade clang to use llvm-link instead of /usr/bin/ld for linking, but I see nothing in the documentation about how to do that.  Just setting $LD to llvm-link doesn't appear to help.

Those undefined references are likely red herrings: If I nm -o libpython3.2m.a (or llvm-nm -o libpython3.2m.a - both work), I can see that at least one of these symbols really is defined (according to nm of course - other tools could perhaps, and likely do, have  other ideas).

Ultimately I want to generate llvm bitcode rather than an ELF binary, but it'd be a satisfying mini-milestone to get a working python ELF binary with llvm first.

I'm currently using the following for compilation:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/llvm/bin:$PATH
prefix=/usr/local/p3ib-3.2
export CC='clang'
export AR='llvm-ar'
export LD='llvm-link -emit-llvm-bc'
export RANLIB='llvm-ranlib'
./configure --prefix="$prefix" && make -j 3
```

Thanks!

Comment: So, you are compiling sources with `-emit-llvm`?

Comment: I've edited the question to answer this.  The short version is "no".

Comment: I see. How about setting `LDFLAGS` to `-emit-llvm`?